# How to create index on two columns, with the key ordering (sorting) specified, using sequelize-cli (MS SQL db)?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

I'm using the Sequelize-CLI migrations for my project. 
I want to create a migration that adds the CLUSTERED index on two of my columns (id and date). I want to set the date sorting to DESC

Here's the QUERY that I basically want to perform:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_id_date ON [dbName].[dbo].[table] ([id], [date] DESC)
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```js
return queryInterface.addIndex(tableName, ['id', 'date'],
        {
          name: 'IX_id_date',
          type: 'CLUSTERED'
        })
```

but I have no idea how I can add the `DESC` option on `date` column index. 
Didn't find the solution in the sequelize docs, and anywhere on stackoverflow.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how to do this just using cli commands but you can edit the generated script to something as below,

```
return queryInterface.addIndex(tableName,
        [{ attribute: 'id', order: 'DESC' }, { attribute: 'date', order: 'DESC' }],
        {
          name: 'IX_id_date',
          type: 'CLUSTERED'
        })
```

Note: I'm using following sequlize versions.

```
"sequelize": "^5.22.3",
"sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The ColumnName3 is also a column in a table. You can use the order as **ASC** or **DESC** as per your requirement.